# React Formik Cannot set property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to set up a basic form in Formik following the [Formik mini course](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwy091304p) by Andrew Mead. My form is:

```
const Household = ({
    values,
    errors,
    touched

}) => (
    <Form>
        <div>
            <Field
            type="string" name="household_name"  placeholder="Household Name" 
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <Field
                type="string" name="name"  placeholder="Family Name" 
            />
        </div>

</Form>
```

)

I am setting it up below but I keep getting  "Cannot set property 'props' of undefined" for household_name. I realize that I need to declare houshold_name someplace but I am not sure where. I thought that it was implicitly declared.

How do I fix this?

```
const FormikApp = Formik({
    mapPropsToValues({ household_name, name}) {
        return {
            household_name: household_name || "",
            name: name || ""

        }
    },
})(Household)
```

Answer (score 3):

just had the same problem. Just add the 'with' before the Formik and it should work.

```
const FormikApp = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues({ household_name, name}) {
        return {
            household_name: household_name || "",
            name: name || ""

        }
    },
})(Household)
```